# Extrude from inside a rounded cube

Tags: extrude

Huge help:
Is there any way I can extrude faces from inside a cube? I ended up with the body shape I want from the mascot I need to make but have now realized I need to pull out the arm (just like the cilinder I made) and the cube face I initially made ocupies all the side shape :(

[image]

Comment: you mean you want to add the arm without losing the whole shape?

Comment: yes. it's impossible, right? I think I'll add the cilinder and work from it, it just worries me that the intersection between the two shapes (body and arm) looks too fake..

Comment: you can inset the side face, then extrude slightly outwards, then extrude again to make the arm

Comment: aaaah I guess that's it! I'll just try to keep the shape as it was after I insert the new face. Thanks!!

Comment: exactly, after the inset you'll need to move the face a bit so that you round back the shape a bit